# Debug symbols for asp.net core

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, debug-symbols

Im trying to find debug symbols for the released version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies. The latest stable version available on nuget is 1.1.2. As far as im aware, ive added all the appropriate symbol servers. The load info tells me its checking here:

```
 - C:\Program Files\dotnet\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb:
 - C:\Users\*snip*\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies\1.1.2\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb:
 - C:\b\w\d6337ac2abf63a4b\.repositories\Security\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies\bin\Release\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb:
 - C:\Windows\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb:   
 - C:\Windows\symbols\dll\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb:
 - C:\Windows\dll\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb:
 - D:\VSSymbolCache\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb\948e7690e7904496862761f01360a70b1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb:
 - D:\VSSymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb\948e7690e7904496862761f01360a70b1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.pdb:
 - https://nuget.smbsrc.net: 
 - http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public:
 - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols:
 - https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols:
```

What am i missing? Is there anywhere i can download the PDBs manually?

Answer (score 0):

Get the source code on GitHub and compile it: https://github.com/aspnet/Security It's working like a charm. I don't know a way to get the PBD alone.